# Django: Display attributes of Person model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a page where a user can see all of his/her personal information. Currently, the user can see their "first_name", "last_name", "email", and "username". However, I want them to be able to see their "age", "city", and "state" which they have entered.

Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

HTML for info page:

```
<table border="1" width="35%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">First name:</td>
        <td align="center">{{user.first_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Last name:</td>
        <td align="center">{{user.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Username:</td>
        <td align="center">{{user.username}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Email Address:</td>
        <td align="center">{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Age:</td>
        <td align="center">{{ Person.age }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">City:</td>
        <td align="center">{{Person.city}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">State:</td>
        <td align="center">{{Person.state}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to get this info to display?

Comment: Try `user.person.city`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to go one step further to access data from related tables `user.person`. [Here is the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships)

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">Age:</td>
    <td align="center">{{ user.person.age }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">City:</td>
    <td align="center">{{ user.person.city }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">State:</td>
    <td align="center">{{ user.person.state }}</td>
</tr>
```